# Get Cloud Firestore database collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from my database hierarchy db.collection/doc/collection/
[image: !https://imgur.com/a/wwOQiXV]

I need to get the data from the collection "product"

I can already filter out the right document, by using this snippet.
Still, didn't manage to get any data from the next collection.

```
db.collection('deliveryservice').where('owner_id', '==', user.uid).collection('product').get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
```

Comment: i don't understand why you used `where`. When you can use `doc` to use document reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following way to retrieve data from your `product` collection.

```
var docRef = db.collection("deliveryservice").doc(user.uid).collection('product');

docRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => { 
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
})
```